# Creating an interaction effect with data that is aggregated to a daily level

Tags: regression, interaction, aggregation

This is my first question so apologies if I am not providing enough information or context. I am working with a dataset where my dependent and most independent variables are at a daily level, but two independent variables ($X_1$ and $X_2$) are originally at the minute level and have been summed and aggregated to a daily level so that every variable in my final data frame is now at the daily level. I would like to build a linear regression with an interaction term, $X_1$ * $X_2$. Can I create the interaction term before aggregating the data to a daily level or is there an argument to creating it before or after aggregating it?

Comment: Since you have the minute/level data, why not do both and see how different it comes out_

Comment: That's a good idea. Due to some interpretational reasons, I'd like to create the interaction at the minute level so I primarily wanted to see if there was any reason I cannot or should not do this.